# Referencing arrays that are nested within multiple objects within MongoDB with Express js

Tags: angularjs, node.js, mongodb, express

So in my MongoDB Collection I have this structure:

```
 "_id" : "Object("-----------")
 "name" : "John Doe"
 "tool" : {
    "hammer" : {
        "name" : "hammer 1",
        "characteristics" : [ 
            {
                "length" : "9 inches"
            }, 
            {
                "weight" : "4 pounds"
            }
        ]
```

I know the data may seem a little strange but I can't put the actual data online so I had to input some dummy data.  So essentially what I would like to do is be able to update the array that is nested within those objects. So I would like to be able to update the weight or add a new characteristic that I haven't previously entered into it. So for example, add in "metal" : "steel" as a new entry into the array. Currently I'm using a Rest API built in Node.js and Express.js to edit the db. When I was trying to figure out how to dig down this deep I was able to do it with an array at the highest level, however I haven't been able to figure out how to access an array when its embedded like this.  So what I was wondering if anybody knew if it was even possible to edit an array this far down? I can post code from controller.js and server.js file if needed but I figured I'd see if it's even possible to do before I start posting it. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Have you tried [$push](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/update/push/)? should be able to test it pretty easily from the cmd line or a tool like robomongo.

Comment: This is the findandmodify function I was using to edit it. However I couldn't seem to get it to edit the array. app.put('/tool/:id', function (req, res) {
      var id = req.params.id;
      console.log(req.body.name);
      db.users.findAndModify({
        query: {_id: mongojs.ObjectId(id)},
        update: {$push: {length:     req.body.tool.hammer.characteristic.length}},
       new: true}, function (err, doc) {
         res.json(doc);
        }
      );
    });

Comment: I thought you were adding to the characteristics not modifying one. That's two diff operations. $push would add to it, to modify you'll have to just update whole document.

Answer (score 0):

You can use findAndModify to $push it into the array.  You have to specify the path precisely though:

```
db.tools.findAndModify( {
   query: { name: "John Doe"},
   update: { $push: { tool.hammer.characteristics: {metal: "steel"} }
} );
```